# different results from different models for 3-way interactions in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, interaction

I am new in R and this is my first question. I have a dataset and need to find a 2-way and two 3-way interactions between my variables.

Specifically, my variables:

a = outcome

b = predictor 1

c = predictor 2

d = predictor 3

e = predictor 4

I need to calculate all main effects and

b * c

b * c * d

b * c * e

I created 2 different models after centering my predictors:

```
m1 <- lm(a ~ b * c * (d+e), data)
```

this gives all main effects and interactions I am interested in but in addition to them, it also gives some other interactions.

```
m2 <- lm(a ~ b + c + d + e + b * c + b * c * d + b * c * e, data)
```

this gives exactly what I want.

The thing is the results differ between models and I do not know which one I should use. The b * c is significant one model, but not significant in the other.

Any recommendation is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your two models are functionally equivalent:

```
> attr(terms(~ b * c * (d+e)),"factors")
  b c d e b:c b:d b:e c:d c:e b:c:d b:c:e
b 1 0 0 0   1   1   1   0   0     1     1
c 0 1 0 0   1   0   0   1   1     1     1
d 0 0 1 0   0   1   0   1   0     1     0
e 0 0 0 1   0   0   1   0   1     0     1

> attr(terms(~ b + c + d + e + b * c + b * c * d + b * c * e),"factors")
  b c d e b:c b:d c:d b:e c:e b:c:d b:c:e
b 1 0 0 0   1   1   0   1   0     1     1
c 0 1 0 0   1   0   1   0   1     1     1
d 0 0 1 0   0   1   1   0   0     1     0
e 0 0 0 1   0   0   0   1   1     0     1
```

except that the order of the `c:d` and `b:e` terms differ in the expansion.

You can't easily--and you shouldn't--evaluate the "significance" of an individual two-way interaction coefficient when it's involved in three-way interactions, as your `b:c` interaction is. Unless there's some coding error, I suspect that your 2 models would make identical outcome predictions for any given combination of predictor-variable values, and that the apparent discrepancy in "significance" for that coefficient is thus irrelevant.